# Why do I get a number when I stream the result of tolower() to std::cout, but not when I use putchar()?

Tags: c++, cout, putchar

I was trying to write a program which will convert every word(either upper or lower case) in the upper or lower case(depending on which case is max).So here is my program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cctype>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s[101];
    int c=0, sm=0, i;

    cin>>s;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        if(s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z')
            c++;
        else
            sm++;
    }

    if(sm>c)
    {
        for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        {
            //cout<<tolower(s[i])<<endl;
            putchar(tolower(s[i]));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        {
            //cout<<toupper(s[i])<<endl;
            putchar(toupper(s[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

**But i was surprised to see that if i write these statement**

```
if(sm>c)
    {
        for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        {
            cout<<tolower(s[i])<<endl;                
        }
    }
```

***or***

```
else
    {
        for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        {
            //cout<<toupper(s[i])<<endl;
            putchar(toupper(s[i]));
        }
    }
```

***then it seems that output is in ASCII number.Can anyone explain me these reason.I am new to c++, so not much aware of cout***

Comment: `toupper()` is a function that accepts an argument of type `int`, and returns an `int`.      Streaming an `int` to `cout` (or any stream) outputs the numeric value.  If you want the corresponding `char`, convert back to `char` before outputting.

Comment: @Peter Use the answer section please. Hover your mouse over the "add a comment" link to discover what comments are for. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::tolower()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) and [`std::toupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) functions return value is int. And `std::cout` print the exact value that appears to it.

So `cout<< tolower(s[i])<<endl` print ASCII value of the characters. But when you write `putchar(toupper(s[i]))` then `putchar()` function automatically converts the ASCII value to characters. That's why you get character as output.

In order to use `cout<< tolower(s[i]) << endl` you need to typecast the ASCII value to character.

So write -

```
cout<< (char)(toupper[i]) <<endl;
cout<< (char)(tolower[i]) <<endl;
```

Comment: Thanks.Didn't know **tolower(), toupper() functions return value is int**.But thought it might be,but was surprised to see that putchar worked!!.Now i can understand,why it happend.Thanks for the answer

Comment: @mahinhossen that is what happens when you don't read the documentation

Answer (score 4):

The reason behind this is the `tolower()`. The return type of `tolower()` is int.

That means its equivalent to printing an integer, rather than a character.

If you want to show it correctly, use this:

```
cout << static_cast<char>(tolower(s[i])) << "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add that this is a false comparison.

The C++ equivalent of `putchar` is [`ostream::put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put), like this:

```
std::cout.put(std::tolower(s[i]));
```

Because both this and `putchar` take a `char`, an implicit conversion is performed. This is necessary because `tolower` gives you an `int` (for historical reasons, sort of).

The streaming operator `<<` is far more general, and has overloads for all sorts of types so that it can format your data for you. Since you're giving it an `int`, and not particularly asking for a `char`, a number is what you get.

Answer (score 1):

From the cplusplus.com reference for [`tolower`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/):

> The value is returned as an int value that can be implicitly casted to char.

However printing the returned int will not convert it to a char. You can explicitly cast it:

```
std::cout<< (char) tolower(s[i])<<endl;
```

[However a static cast is safer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/8534008)

```
std::cout << static_cast<char>(tolower(s[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

cout prints the value, and in C++ a tolower returns a int (ASCII) so what you get is that, if you want to yell the actual character you need to convert manually the output.

```
cout<<static_cast<char>((s[i]))<<endl;
```

[Online editor to C++ (example)](http://cpp.sh/7k47k)

Comment: It's very intelligent, which is why it's doing what the code asked it to! Taking an integer and printing its ASCII equivalent instead would be very stupid and annoying.

Comment: `static_cast` is not required in the example that you gave in answer. Even without that, I expected it to work and It did. Because different overloads of << is provided for different data types. If you are passing a `char` as a parameter to << operator, its ASCII value won't be printed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
if(sm>c)
    {
        for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        {
            cout<<tolower(s[i])<<endl;                
        }
    }
```

yes you should expect an ASCII value. This is because tolower is a function that returns an integer and cout outputs directly what it is given, it doesnt carry out any manipulation.

However you said that in this case:

```
else
    {
        for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        {
            //cout<<toupper(s[i])<<endl;
            putchar(toupper(s[i]));
        }
    }
```

you also get an ASCII value but I think your mistaken. This should output a character because the putchar() function not only outputs what it is given but beforehand carries out manipulation to ensure it is in char format.